# ¿Como saber cuantas veces se repite letras?

Tags: java, contador

Tengo el siguiente código, pero quiero que muestre por ejemplo: **al escribir un texto, como Casa Muestre, la letra C se repite 1 vez, la letra A se repite dos veces, la letra S se repite 1 vez etc.** ¿Cómo lo podría realizar?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);
String cadena = "";
char [] Arraycadena;
char caracter;
int contador=0;

System.out.println ("Ingrese un texto: ");
cadena = lector.nextLine();
Arraycadena = cadena.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < Arraycadena.length; i++){
    caracter = Arraycadena [i];

    for (int j = 0; j <Arraycadena.length; j++){
        if (Arraycadena[j] == caracter) {
            contador++;

        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arraycadena[i]+ ""+ contador);
    contador = 0;

}
```

}

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías hacer un [Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) por palabra, e insertar cada letra. A medida q recorres la palabra, te fijas si ya estaba insertada la letra y le sumas +1 al valor si estaba y si no, la agregas y le das  un valor de 1.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? ¿Por qué no sabes hacerlo? La verdad, suena a que quieres te hagamos un ejercicio de clase de programación :- /

Comment: Si, ya lo intente, acabo de actualizar el código!

Comment: @sanzante esa  no es manera de contestar, nadie nace sabiendo, para eso se generan este tipo de foros en los cuales se comparte lo que uno aprende. Independiente de que quiera que resuelva su código o no, no tendrías por que responder con un comentario de esa forma.

Comment: @cignius He preguntado qué ha hecho, que ya me parece suficiente porque no indica que haya intentando nada. Y me parece que la respuesta fuera de lugar es la tuya, mis formas son perfectamente correctas. Aquí se resuelven dudas, no se hace el trabajo de los demás.

Comment: Podrias explicar la logica de tu codigo? creo que si lo podes explicar vas a ver donde estas fallando.. en ningun lado estas contando cada letra.. solo incrementando un contador.. pero tu contador deberia ser por letra...

Comment: @SwanAndres estaría bien que explicases por qué falla, o mostrar al menos unos ejemplos de entrada y el resultado que saca.

Comment: Subí una imagen de lo que muestra. @sanzante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando un HashMap, de esta manera no se repiten los valores. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);
String cadena = "";
System.out.println ("Ingrese un texto: ");
cadena = lector.nextLine();
Map<Character, Integer> numChars = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); ++i)
{
    char charAt = cadena.charAt(i);

    //Se busca si la letra en el HashMap, como no existe la agregamos con un '1'
    if (!numChars.containsKey(charAt))
    {
        numChars.put(charAt, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //Como la letra ya existe vamos por el contador de esa letra y 
        //le sumamos uno y la agregamos 'remplazando' la letra anterior
        numChars.put(charAt, numChars.get(charAt) + 1);
    }
}

//Aquí imprimo el HashMap con los resultados 
System.out.println(numChars);

//o aquí la forma de iterar el HashMap
Iterator it = numChars.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove();
}
```

Lo que hacemos es que primero se busca en el HashMap, si la letra no existe se agrega con un 1, si la letra existe se obtiene el contador de esta letra y se le agrega 1, lo que se hace es 'remplazar' la letra por la misma letra, pero con su valor incrementado, ya que por tratarse de un HashMap no agrega otra letra como pasa en un ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es cómo has estructurado la solución.

Lo que haces es recorrer la cadena en el primer bucle. En cada vuelta del bucle vuelves a recorrer la cadena entera, sumando uno cada vez que encuentras la letra del carácter actual. Al final de cada vuelta del bucle exterior escribes la letra actual con las veces que lo has contado. Esto produce el efecto que ves. Por ejemplo, cuentas dos veces cuantas 'a' hay, una vez cuando encuentras la primera 'a' de 'casa', y otra vez cuando encuentras la segunda 'a'.

Tienes que reestructurar tu solución de la siguiente forma:

Inicialmente define una variable de tipo diccionario. Esto es una variable compleja que tiene claves y valores. Por cada clave puedes especificar un valor, y las claves son únicas. Es decir, solo puedes tener un valor para una clave determinada. Digamos que se llama `contadorLetras`.

Debes usar un único bucle que recorra la cadena. En cada vuelta del bucle lo que haces es determinar la letra y luego usarla para acceder a contadorLetras, sumando uno al valor asociado a la clave de la letra actual. Algo como esto (en pseudocódigo):

```
if (contadorLetras[caracter] es nulo) {
  contadorLetras[caracter] = 1;
}
else {
  contadorLetras[caracter]++; // o contadorLetras[caracter] = contadorLetras[caracter] + 1;
}
```

Es decir, que la cuando encuentre la 'c' de 'casa', hará que contadorLetras['c'] sea 1. Al encontrar la primera 'a' hará lo mismo con la 'a', fijando el valor a 1. Con la 's' igual. Pero al encontrar la segunda 'a' lo que hará será incrementar el valor de la 'a' en contadorLetras.

Al final del bucle contadorLetras valdrá:

```
contadorLetras[c] = 1
contadorLetras[a] = 2
contadorLetras[s] = 1
```

Solo te queda recorrer contadorLetras para escribir la letra (la clave) y cuántas veces ha sido encontrada (el valor).

Cómo no tengo una MV de Java a mano y hace mucho tiempo que no programo en Java te dejo la implementación a ti. Tendrás que encontrar el tipo adecuado para el la variable contadorLetras, en los comentarios sugieren un [Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Gracias @Hashmap probare